# Center horizontally and vertically inside CSS3 circle

Tags: css, icons, center, font-awesome

Please take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/T7cVg/7/

What I'm trying to do is to get css3 circles with centered icons (both: horizontally and vert.). What am I doing wrong?

http://screencast.com/t/bpxIefbf

As you see, envelope stays in left side, phone too. In other words, position of icons is not in center.

CSS

```
.circle {
    color: #fbfbfb;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #b0b8c2;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #d9dfe6;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    float:left;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="circle">
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
    </div>
          <div class="circle">
                            <i class="icon-phone"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="circle">
                            <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {line-height: 20px}
```

This will work.

Comment: It's pretty centered to me, but if you are not satisfied, feel free to change the `line-height` value.

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/MrPVep7lcd2n this is the screen cast on my screen. Actually you have nothing to do with the font, you set it `text-align:center;`, then it should be. Try to change the `font-size`, it may work.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/T7cVg/8/ How about this? I have updated the jsfiddle. Will this work for you?

```
.circle {
    color: #fbfbfb;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #b0b8c2;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #d9dfe6;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    float:left;
    padding:1em 2%;
}

.circle [class^="icon-"],
.circle [class*=" icon-"] {
    line-height: normal
}
```